# Virtual machine "VuserA" could not be started because the hypervisor is not running

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I am running Ubuntu as my host OS and I'm using virtual box to run both a Windows 10 OS and a Hyper-V. When i use the Hyper-V manager on windows im able to connect to the Hyper-V server and create a virtual machine but once i start it i get the error stated in the title. I have checked the running services and the hypervisor is running. Does this error have something to do with the fact that im running both the hypervisor and windows 10 on virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have an AMD CPU, that's the only architecture currently supported by VirtualBox.

Next, you'll need to be on version 6.0.0 or higher of VirtualBox. Ideally 6.0.6 as of this writing, since it has AMD nested fixes.   VirtualBox change log: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog

Finally, you'll need to shutdown your VM and go to the **Settings** of the VM, then to **System\Processor** and click the box for "**Enable Nested VT-x/AMD-V**".

Note that even though it says VT-x, currently only AMD-v is supported:  See: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90831